# Logout listener getting user details

Tags: spring, http

I have a LogoutListener that implements HttpSessionListener and in the sessionDestroyed method I want to clear the logged in users access context.  In this method I have been unable to get the logged in users details to remove this.  Any help on how to get this would be brilliant.  Thanks.

```
public class LogoutListener implements HttpSessionListener { 
.
.
.
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
```

I tried using the following to get the authentication but it was returning null:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [spring security customize logout handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112972/spring-security-customize-logout-handler)

Comment: Would be better to to use `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler` as a logoutHandler injected into `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter` (and `org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter`, if used).

Comment: You should implement a custom `LogoutHandler` to do the cleanup and register that with the `LogoutFilter`.

Comment: For handling the sessionDestroyed event, you could also implement `ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent>` and then check for a `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent`, but the `SecurityContext` won't be available there either.