# Spring secuirity login/logout - running custom code

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using spring secuirity and I want to add a very simple behaviour when user log in or log out. All I want to do is logging this information on the server. Where can I do that?

Comment: Do you have code ? What did you try ?

Comment: Well does code matter here? There is no typical action method onLogout on Login() and I'm looking for a part of code responsible for it. 
Is this possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is Login and Logout handlers. Spring is so great, and it supports that :-)

Read about [SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) (and [SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.html)). Your answer is there.

As for Logout handler - [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112972/spring-security-customize-logout-handler) (and of course [this article that I wrote a while back](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/521847/Logout-Spring-s-LogoutFilter)) is your answer.

Comment: Dear lord the problem was on precedence side:
`.logoutSuccessHandler(myhandler).logoutUrl("/app/logout").`  instead of `.logoutUrl("/app/logout").logoutSuccessHandler(myhandler)`