# Spring Security Custom Logout

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot app that uses Spring security, but I want to customize it on authentication, but not authorization. I have done login successfully, but I have no idea where do I have to put my logout action.
Here are some of my code:
1. The controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value={"/login"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(){

    return new ModelAndView("pages/login");

    }
```

2. WebSecurityConfig

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
   public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
       private @Autowired CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationManager;
       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
           .authorizeRequests()
               .anyRequest()
                   .authenticated()
               .and()
               .formLogin()
                   .usernameParameter("username")
                   .passwordParameter("password")
                   .failureUrl("/login?error")
                   .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                   .loginPage("/login")
                   .permitAll()
               .and()
                   .logout()
                   .logoutRequestMatcher(
                           new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login?logout")
                   ).logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
               .and()
               .csrf().disable();
       }

       @Autowired
       @Override
       protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.authenticationProvider( authenticationManager );
       }

       @Bean
       protected AuthenticationProvider getServicesAuthenticationProvider() {
       //stackoverflow.com/questions/22453550/custom-authentication-provider-not-being-called/22457561#22457561
            return new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
       }

       @Override
       public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
           web.ignoring()
                   .antMatchers("/**/*.css")
                   .antMatchers("/**/*.js")
                   .antMatchers("/**/*.jpg")
                   .antMatchers("/**/*.png")
                   .antMatchers("/**/*.gif")
                   .antMatchers("/resources/**");
       }
       public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
           PasswordEncoder encoder = NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
           return encoder;
       }
   }
   ```
3. CustomAuthenticationProvider

   ```
   @Component
   public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{
       private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class);
       private @Autowired UAMSLogin uamsLogin;
       private Map<String, Boolean> userLoggedIn = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

       @Override
       public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
           String username = authentication.getPrincipal() + "";
           String password = authentication.getCredentials() + "";
           logger.info("authenticating....");
           if(username.equals("")|| username==null || password.equals("")|| password==null){
               logger.fatal("username or password cannot be empty!");
               return null;
           }
           else if(userLoggedIn.containsKey(username)){
               UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken a = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
               return a;
           }
           try {
               if (uamsLogin.loginUams(username, password)) {
                   logger.info("authentication success");
                   UamsSession sessionInfo = uamsLogin.getUams();
                   logger.info("authentication success");
                   String role = "USER";
                   userLoggedIn.put(username, true);
                   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken a = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
                   return a;
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               logger.info("authentication failed");
               e.printStackTrace();
               throw new BadCredentialsException("1000");
           }
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
           return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
       }
   }
   ```
4. UAMSLogin:

   ```
   @Component
   public class UAMSLogin implements Serializable {


       private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UAMSLogin.class);
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       private static boolean isConnected = false;
       private UamsSession session;
       @Value("${UAMS.SEC_SRV_CONN}")
       private String UAMS_SERVER_CONNECTION;

       @Value("${UAMS.CSM_SERVER_URL}")
       private String UAMS_CSM_SERVER_URL;

       @Value("${amdocs.ticketapplicationid}")
       private String amdocs_ticketapplicationid;

       @Value("${amdocs.ticketparam}")
       private String amdocs_ticketparam;  
       public UAMSLogin(){

       }
       // Login with UAMS
       public boolean loginUams(String username, String password) throws Exception {
           logger.info("loginUams with " + username + "/" + password);
           session = this.createSession();
           logger.info("create session success: "+session.toString());
           String ticket=null;

           logger.info("UamsSystem version: "+UamsSystem.getVersionString());
           try {
               session.ensureSession(username, password);
               ticket = session.getTicket();
               if (ticket != null && ticket !="") {
                   logger.info("login success : " + session.getTicket());
                   isConnected = true;
                   return true;
               } else {
                   logger.info("login failed: ticket is NULL");
                   return false;
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               logger.info("login failed: ", e);
               return false;
           }
       }

       protected UamsSession createSession() throws Exception {
           UamsSession session     = new UamsSession(ReadConfig.readInputStream());

           logger.info("UAMS_SERVER_CONNECTION: "+UAMS_SERVER_CONNECTION);
           logger.info("UAMS_CSM_SERVER_URL: "+UAMS_CSM_SERVER_URL);
           logger.info("amdocs_ticketapplicationid: "+amdocs_ticketapplicationid);
           logger.info("amdocs_ticketparam:  "+amdocs_ticketparam);
           session.setSecurityUrl(UAMS_SERVER_CONNECTION);
           session.setProviderUrl(UAMS_CSM_SERVER_URL);

           session.setApplicationId(amdocs_ticketapplicationid);
           session.setParam(amdocs_ticketparam);
           return session;
       }

       public static boolean isConnected() {
           return isConnected;
       }


       public UamsSession getUams(){
           return session;
       }

   }
   ```

As you can see I am using UAMS to see if this user valid or not. I still don't know how to remember each session, so as you can see there are dirty code HashMap `containsKey`. More importantly, if I make `session.logout(username);` where should I call that??
UAMS is a Jar that used on my company.

If you find this question is not clear I'm very sorry and please ask me.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For convenient, can I do some custom logout in `UAMSLogin` class? How to do it?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand, I guess you want to perform some action on the UAMS library you talked about once the logout is done in Spring Security.

If this is what you are talking about, I would better do it using a custom [LogoutSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutSuccessHandler.html) and binding it in your config to the logout action.

LogoutSuccessHandler interface has just a method you should implement:

```
public class CustomLogoutHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler#onLogoutSuccess(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)
     */
    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        logger.debug("CustomLogoutHandler.onLogoutSuccess");

    }

}
```

Here you could do wathever you need and then even redirect to any page you should go to after session logout.

**EDIT:**

You should use a LogoutSuccessHandler as I said or even better add a [LogoutHandler](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.0.RC1/reference/html/jc.html#jc-logout-handler):

```
public class TaskImplementingLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandler {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler#logout(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)
     */
    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res,
            Authentication authentication) {
        // do whatever you need
    }

}
```

Once you implemented the LogoutHandler that fits your needs, you should add it to your configuration. Have a look at the java security configuration [logout section](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/jc.html#jc-logout)

Your java security config must be like this:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login?logout")
                )
                .addLogoutHandler(new TaskImplementingLogoutHandler())
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
```

Comment: How do I "binding it in my config to the logout action"?

Comment: As you can see I bind the customAuthentication in `configure` method: `auth.authenticationProvider( authenticationManager );`

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your security context xml file:

```
<security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" />
```

With this, you invalidate the user's session when he reaches `urldomain/logout`.

Check a more complex example here: [spring security customize logout handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112972/spring-security-customize-logout-handler)

And some tutorials I've found: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-logout
http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-logout-example/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sory but I don't make any xml file other that pom.xml.
I think I have Spring do it for me. To be honest I'm new to java web, spring, spring boot app (LOL).